# How properly shift arrow head on cubic bezier in SVG to its center

Tags: javascript, svg

There is a cubic bezier with arrow marker:

```
<defs>
  <marker id="arrow" orient="auto" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12" refX="10" refY="6">
    <path d="M0,0 L0,12 L12,6 z"></path>
  </marker>
</defs>

<path marker-end="url(#arrow)" d="M 220 104 C 220 144 400 184 400 224" stroke-width="2"></path>
```

I want to shift arrow head to the center of curve, but when I mutating `refX` attr of `marker` arrow shifts not across the curve but straight to top (http://prntscr.com/ikzuol). It works perfectly with quadratic bezier curves but not with cubic.

Is there a way to display an arrow head at the center of cubic bezier curve with correct orientation using marker?

I know there is an option to get coordinates at length, calculate angle to rotate and do positioning and rotation by myself but I would like to avoid such calculations.

UPD: I've created a codepen to demonstrate the issue: https://codepen.io/onatolich/pen/LQqYvr

UPD2: one more codepen to demonstrate that it's working with quadratic bezier curves: https://codepen.io/onatolich/pen/NyoxQv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`refX` and `refY` are points in the coordinate system the marker is defined in and have no relation to the direction of the path. They simply define the point that is considered the origin of the marker and wich will be placed on the end of the path.

There is no way to define a marker along a computed path. Markers can only be placed at the vertices of a path. So the seemingly straight-forward way would be to find a mid-point, place a vertex there with appropriate cubic bezier control points...

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
<defs>
  <marker id="arrow" orient="auto" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12" refX="3" refY="6">
    <path d="M0,0 L0,12 L12,6 z"></path>
  </marker>
</defs>
<path marker-mid="url(#arrow)"
      d="M 220,104 C 220,124 265,143 310,162.5 355,182 400,202 400,224"
      stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="transparent"></path>
</svg>
```

...but that is obviously a lot of computation, also.

Here is a hack that uses the [`<animateMotion>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement) element, not to animate anything, but because it can move an object to every point along a path. The movement just starts, ends, and freezes in the middle of the path.

The "marker" does not have its own viewport, which means there is no way to define a `refX`/`refY`. The point to be placed on the path is always at (0,0) of its userspace coordinates. That is the reason the marker has to be moved in the opposite direction of these values.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" >
  <path id="path1" d="M 220 104 C 220 144 400 180 400 224"
        fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" />
  <path d="M0,0 L0,12 L12,6 z" transform="translate(-3,-6)">
    <animateMotion dur="0s" rotate="auto" fill="freeze"
                   keyTimes="0;1" keyPoints="0.5;0.5" calcMode="linear" >
       <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path1"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>
```

The hack will not work with Edge/IE, which do not implement SMIL animations.

Comment: Why this example with quadratic bezier is working then? https://codepen.io/onatolich/pen/NyoxQv

Comment: animateMotion is interesting approach but unfortunately IE11 support is crucial for me.

Comment: Your codepen is working only incedentally because the path is almost straight up to the point where the marker sits. Set refX to 100 or 150 and see that it deviates to the side.

Comment: I see what you're talking about. Hm. Seems like I'll need to perform all calculation by myself. Thank you! I will mark your answer as correct even though it does not work in IE.

Comment: @RobertLongson `rotate="auto"` is not [implemented](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/status.html). Getting the point along the path is [four lines of code](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile/blob/23c5ceae10d95695021cd51f2f45cb5d3e4b5132/smil.user.js#L981), so it's just not worth it.

Comment: @ccprog "Ka**i**ido" I missed the notification (better always use the autocomplete to avoid that). And yes, as my edit comment states, Chrome requires it, and actually webkit too.

Comment: Also note that `paced` is the default `calcMethod` for `animateMotion`.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the explanation, I actually missed the commit message. I can't make out a difference in Chromium 73 / Debian, what is supposed to be the problem?

Comment: With `paced` (or default), the arrow stays at offset `0` Chrome 81 - 83 macOs + Windows & Safari 13.1 macOs